# Etiqueta [mail] debiera ser sinónimo de [email]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

La etiqueta [mail](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mail) debiera ser sinónimo de [email](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email).

He intentado sugerir el sinónimo, pero no tengo la puntuación suficiente en la etiqueta.

Comment: Me parece correcto.. pero demosle un rato de maduración a ver si alguien tiene una opinión diferente...

Comment: no vaya a ser que usemos mail para servidores de correo (no creo, pero habria que revisar)

Comment: En todo caso, si hay que hacer la diferencia entre cliente y servidor, esa quizás sería una etiqueta del tipo `servidor-email`, o algo similar, pero no creo que `mail` y `email` hagan suficiente diferencia.

Comment: uno nunca sabe con lo que pueden salir en los distintos españoles que manejamos ;) (sigo pensando que es correcto eh...)

Comment: Y ademas, alguien la tiene que jugar de malvado, para que todos estemos todavia mas de acuerdo :)

Comment: No hablas de Trump, verdad? jajaja. :D

Comment: [tag:mail] actualmente tiene apenas dos preguntas, por lo que renombrar debería ser el primer paso y luego crear el sinónimo (y hacer _merge_) para que no se reproduzca. [tag:email] tiene casi 300. También existe [tag:mailer] con dos.

Comment: Si, y es de reciente creación, por eso mismo sugerí el sinónimo. Por lo pronto, ya he editado las preguntas para renombrar el tag, pero ya que se ha comenzado a utilizar, sigo sugiriendo que se declaren como sinónimos. :)

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con jachguate, deben ser sinónimos.

Comment: La etiqueta dejo de aparecer al no tener preguntas. Si vuelve a aparecer, la hacemos sinonimo.

Comment: @gbianchi yo entendí que la idea era hacer merge, combinarlas. Para ello no hace falta que exista

Comment: me mataste @fedorqui.. si no existe que merge hago? la creo y la mergeo?

Comment: @gbianchi la herramienta debería estar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/admin/create-tag-synonym Allí defines los sinónimos incluso sin que existan. Si seleccionas _merge_ (no sé cómo estará traducido), te hace el sinónimo y las junta.

Comment: @fedorqui para algo tenemos de quien aprender ;) muchisimas gracias

Comment: @gbianchi no por nada pero veo que [tag:mail] no está creada. No sé qué decidisteis pero pensé que las uniríais.

Comment: @gbianchi, me doy cuenta hoy que esto tiene status-completado y, sin embargo, existen ambas etiquetas y no son sinónimos. ¿Es intencional?